# Generating Synthetic Instances from Rules

Tags: r

```r
require(dplyr)
require(RRF)
require(inTrees)

## Data PreProcessing
german_credit <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/german.data")
colnames(german_credit) <- c("chk_acct", "duration", "credit_his", "purpose", "amount", 
"saving_acct", "present_emp", "installment_rate", "sex", "other_debtor","present_resid", "property", 
 "age", "other_install", "housing", "n_credits", "job", "n_people", "telephone", "foreign", "response")

german_credit$response <- german_credit$response - 1
german_credit$response <- as.factor(german_credit$response)
german_credit <- data.frame(german_credit,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

LevelNum <- function(x) {x <- as.factor(x); levels(x) <- 1:length(unique(x)); return(x)}
MinMaxNorm <- function(x) {x <- as.numeric(x); MaxX <- max(x); MinX <- min(x) ; return((x - MinX)/(MaxX - MinX))}
german_credit <- german_credit %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, LevelNum) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.integer, MinMaxNorm)

## Simple IID Bootstrapping with equal probability selection and replacement
NRow_GCredit <- nrow(german_credit)
PERC <- 0.7
PROBS <- rep(1, NRow_GCredit)/NRow_GCredit
TrainID <- sample(1:NRow_GCredit, PERC*NRow_GCredit, prob = PROBS, replace = TRUE)
TestID <- setdiff(1:NRow_GCredit, TrainID)
Ytrain <- german_credit %>% dplyr::select(response)  %>% dplyr::slice(TrainID)  
Ytest  <- german_credit %>% dplyr::select(response)  %>% dplyr::slice(TestID)  
Xtrain <- german_credit %>% dplyr::select(!response) %>% dplyr::slice(TrainID)
Xtest  <- german_credit %>% dplyr::select(!response) %>% dplyr::slice(TestID)

## Emd/ Data PreProcessing 
rf <- RRF::RRF(Xtrain, Ytrain$response, ntree = 500) # build an ordinary RF
ruleExec <- inTrees::extractRules(RF2List(rf), Xtrain, digits = 4) # transform to R-executable rules
YbyRules <- sapply(ruleExec, function(x) { 
  ZZ <- Ytrain[eval(parse(text = x))]
  length(ZZ[ZZ == Minority])/length(ZZ)
})
MinSortedRules <- sort(YbyRules, decreasing = TRUE) 
MinorityRules <- MinSortedRules[MinSortedRules>0.5]
```

This generates rules such as this:

```
"X[,3] %in% c('1') & X[,6] %in% c('2','3','5') & X[,13]<=0.1786 & X[,17] %in% c('3')"
```

i.e.:

- The third variable is level 1
- The 6th variable is level 2,3,5
- The 13th variable is <=0.1786
- The 17th variable is level 3
- The other variables are allowed to vary

I am stuck as to how to generate random synthetic observation from this rule.

Comment: To use a tree as a generative model, walk down the tree choosing one branch or another at each level. When you get to a leaf, generate a sample at random and let that be the output. Sampling at the leaf nodes requires having some notion of p(data | leaf), and there are probably several reasonable choices. Maybe the simplest is to sample from a Gaussian bump which has the same mean and variance as the mean and variance of training data falling on that leaf. Also, branches must be chosen according to mass on one branch or the other. Followups to stats.stackexchange.com. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Oh, if you need to sample from the dependent variable, same business about branches applies, and then when you get to a leaf, sample from the dependent variable distribution there. For binary response, that probably means something like tossing a coin to get 0 or 1 with probability = #(positive cases in leaf)/#(total cases in leaf).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wanted something more "messy." I wanted to use these "smeared" synthetic instances in an ensemble framework to take advantage of the hump shaped performance of mild randomness present in hyperspace ensembling. I feel that using purely a decision tree/random forest as a generative model would be too restrictive.

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify what it is that you are trying to do. At this point I can't tell. Further questions should be posted to stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. This is very slow...obviously not multi-threaded. This is too random and will inherently bias the data. A simple control can be the application of KNN to bound the non-selected variables or a Neater/TGT control on synthetic data.

```
 RepeatSynGen<-function(MinorityRules,X,Xtrain,Minority,NBoot,i,UniqueCrit=10){ 

         X<-Xtrain; FullInfo<-1:nrow(Xtrain)
         ZZ<-strsplit(attributes(MinorityRules[1])$names,"&")[[1]] %>% as.list
         FindFirstNum<-function(ZZ){as.numeric(sub("\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", ZZ))}

         IncII<-do.call(c,lapply(1:length(ZZ),function(U){FindFirstNum(ZZ[[U]])}))
         NotInc<-(1:ncol(Xtrain))[!(1:ncol(Xtrain) %in% IncII)]
         NotIncCrit<-rep("FullInfo",length(NotInc))
         FullNum<-c(IncII,NotInc)

         ZZPrime<-vector(mode = "list", length = ncol(Xtrain))
         ZZPrime<-do.call(c, list(ZZ, NotIncCrit))
         ZZPrime <- ZZPrime[order(FullNum)]
         ClassDF<-sapply(Xtrain,class)
         UniqueLevel<-sapply(Xtrain,function(U){length(unique(U))})

         SynInstance<-lapply(1:NBoot, function(UU){

                     do.call(data.frame,lapply(1:ncol(Xtrain), function(UU){ ZZP<-ZZPrime[[UU]]
                     EvalZZP<-X[eval(parse(text=ZZP)),UU]
                                             if(ClassDF[UU]=="factor"){sample(EvalZZP,1)
                                                       } else { if(UniqueLevel[UU]<UniqueCrit){sample(EvalZZP,1)
                                                                 } else {runif(1,min(EvalZZP),max(EvalZZP))}} 
                                                                                    })) %>% `colnames<-`(colnames(Xtrain))
                                                        }) 


             SynCrit<-do.call(rbind,SynInstance)
             return(do.call(cbind,list(SynCrit,rep(i,NBoot))) %>% `colnames<-`(c(colnames(Xtrain),"Group")))

 }

IMB_Spread<-length(Majority)-length(Minority)
RepeatNSynData<-do.call(rbind,lapply(1:IMB_Spread,function(i){RepeatSynGen(MinorityRules[i],X,Xtrain,NBoot=50,i=i,UniqueCrit=10)}))
```